# Scalable and maintanable way to use single url param shared with different components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using the browser url to persist the application state.
Selections of the components on the page for example.
For different reasons one url parameter can be updated by two different component on that page.
so it can be 
_q=A1 AND A2 AND B1

And in a third component I just take this url param and call the api with it.

Architecture wise it makes sense to split _q and have two different url params and then just combine them into one before the api call. Lets' say I don't want to go in that direction.

Is there a simple way to update this shared url param?

Because now in componentWillReceiveProps I have to parse it and extract only the part that belongs to that particular component and ignore the rest. And when the component updates its state and needs to update the shared url param I need to "backup" the rest of the data and change only part of this url param.

It's too complicated and error prone, is there a better way except just split it into two separate parameters?

Comment: Simple way forward: write a function that can extract your parameters from the query string, and another that can serialize a bag of parameters to the query string. Use these functions to unpack, modify and repack values into the string.

Comment: Your hierarchy is not listed, but I imagine they have a common parent. I would use the parent as the parser and maintainer of state that is then passed to the child components. This will give you one source of truth for the parsing and state.